# Question based on combinations

Tags: combinatorics

My question is if we are given a list of unique digits then how many different numbers can we form from them which satisfies a condition i.e no digit should be at its original place.!

example,
if digits are: $1, 2, 3, 4$
then the req numbers are: 
$2143,
2341,
2413,
3142,
3412,
3421,
4123,
4312,
4321 $
i.e answer is $9$!

Comment: First:  in a combinatorics environment, you should _never_ place an exclamation point after a number: that means $9$ factorial, not $9$ with emphasis.  Second: these are called _derangements_.  You can find more information on Wikipedia, or by searching on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problems are called [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)problems.
The derangement formula can be found here: http://math.illinoisstate.edu/day/courses/old/305/contentderangements.html

Comment: wonderful! thanks.!